# Eventual consistency - how to avoid phantoms

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, hazelcast, ignite, high-availability

I am new to the topic. Having read a handful of articles on it, and asked a couple of persons, I still do not understand what you people do in regard to one problem.

There are UI clients making requests to several backend instances (for now it's irrelevant whether sessions are sticky or not), and those instances are connected to some highly available DB cluster (may it be Cassandra or something else of even Elasticsearch). Say the backend instance is not specifically tied to one or cluster's machines, and instead its every request to DB may be served by a different machine.
One client creates some record, it's synchronously of asynchronously stored to one of cluster's machines then eventually gets replicated to the rest of DB machines. Then another client requests the list or records, the request ends up served by a distant machine not yet received the replicated changes, and so the client does not see the record. Well, that's bad but not yet ugly.

Consider however that the second client hits the machine which has the record, displays it in a list, then refreshes the list and this time hits the distant machine and again does not see the record. That's very weird behavior to observe, isn't it? It might even get worse: the client successfully requests the record, starts some editing on it, then tries to store the updates to DB and this time hits the distant machine which says "I know nothing about this record you are trying to update". That's an error which the user will see while doing something completely legitimate.

So what's the common practice to guard against this?
So far, I only see three solutions.

1) Not actually a solution but rather a policy: ignore the problem and instead speed up the cluster hard enough to guarantee that 99.999% of changes will be replicated on the whole cluster in, say, 0.5 secord (it's hard to imagine some user will try to make several consecutive requests to one record in that time; he can of course issue several reading requests, but in that case he'll probably not notice inconsistency between results). And even if sometimes something goes wrong and the user faces the problem, well, we just embrace that. If the loser gets unhappy and writes a complaint to us (which will happen maybe once a week or once an hour), we just apologize and go on.

2) Introduce an affinity between user's session and a specific DB machine. This helps, but needs explicit support from the DB, and also hurts load-balancing, and invites complications when the DB machine goes down and the session needs to be re-bound to another machine (however with proper support from DB I think that's possible; say Elasticsearch can accept routing key, and I believe if the target shard goes down it will just switch the affinity link to another shard - though I am not entirely sure; but even if re-binding happens, the other machine may contain older data :) ).

3) Rely on monotonic consistency, i.e. some method to be sure that the next request from a client will get results no older than the previous one. But, as I understand it, this approach also requires explicit support from DB, like being able so pass some "global version timestamp" to a cluster's balancer, which it will compare with it's latest data on all machines' timestamps to determine which machines can serve the request.

Are there other good options? Or are those three considered good enough to use?

P.S. My specific problem right now is with Elasticsearch; AFAIK there is no support for monotonic reads there, though looks like option #2 may be available.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite has primary partition for a key and backup partitions. Unless you have `readFromBackup` option set, you will always be reading from primary partition whose contents is expected to be reliable.

If a node goes away, a transaction (or operation) should be either propagated by remaining nodes or rolled back.

Note that Apache Ignite doesn't do Eventual Consistency but instead Strong Consistency. It means that you can observe delays during node loss, but will not observe inconsistent data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of that. In terms of my initial question, it essentially is solution #2, only client-ignorant. But, wait a minute, there can be multiple backups of same entry, right? Then they have to only consider a query complete when all backups received replicae of data, and that's susceptible to partitioning problems. But if they say it's still consistent, then it probably somehow is.

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra if using at least quorum consistency for both reads and writes you will get monotonic reads. This was not the case pre 1.0 but thats a long time ago. There are some gotchas if using server timestamps but thats not by default so likely wont be an issue if using C* 2.1+.

What can get funny is since C* uses timestamps is things that occur at "same time". Since Cassandra is Last Write Wins the times and clock drift do matter. But concurrent updates to records will always have race conditions so if you require strong read before write guarantees you can use light weight transactions (essentially CAS operations using paxos) to ensure no one else updates between your read to update, these are slow though so I would avoid it unless critical.

Comment: I don't know much of Cassandra, but I found this: "For instance, Cassandra guarantees most of the time that if you write successfully to a quorum of nodes, any subsequent read from a quorum of nodes will see that write or one with a greater timestamp." - notice "most of the time" and "read from a quorum of nodes". Well, of course a node (one of a quorum) received a replica it will respond with an updated data. But no one says our client's request will be routed to a node from a quorum, right? A client may read fresh data from one node and then read stale state of same data from other node.

Comment: with a quorum read you will guarantee that there will be overlap with at least one node that has the last full quorum write (since your checking more than half the nodes, and writes go to more than half the nodes). The only situation where this is an issue is when a new write is partially committed (not full quorum yet), but then a 2nd read goes to only the nodes that are uncommitted. In which case the 2nd read is getting older data than the first read. To prevent this the read repairs became blocking to ensure the reads are monotonic - see CASSANDRA-2494 that was fixed in 2011.

Answer (score 1):

In a true distributed system, it does not matter where your record is stored in remote cluster as long as your clients are connected to that remote cluster. In Hazelcast, a record is always stored in a partition and one partition is owned by one of the servers in the cluster. There could be X number of partitions in the cluster (by default 271) and all those partitions are equally distributed across the cluster. So a 3 members cluster will have a partition distribution like 91-90-90.

Now when a client sends a record to store in Hazelcast cluster, it already knows which partition does the record belong to by using consistent hashing algorithm. And with that, it also knows which server is the owner of that partition. Hence, the client sends its operation directly to that server.  This approach applies on all client operations - put or get. So in your case, you may have several UI clients connected to the cluster but your record for a particular user is stored on one server in the cluster and all your UI clients will be approaching that server for their operations related to that record.

As for consistency, Hazelcast by default is strongly consistent distributed cache, which implies that all your updates to a particular record happen synchronously, in the same thread and the application waits until it has received acknowledgement from the owner server (and the backup server if backups are enabled) in the cluster.

When you connect a DB layer (this could be one or many different types of DBs running in parallel) to the cluster then Hazelcast cluster returns data even if its not currently present in the cluster by reading it from DB. So you never get a null value. On updating, you configure the cluster to send the updates downstream synchronously or asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Ah-ha, after some even more thorough study of ES discussions I found this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html

Note how they specifically highlight the "custom value" case, recommending to use it exactly to solve my problem.

So, given that's their official recommendation, we can summarise it like this.

1. To fight volatile reads, we are supposed to use "preference",
   with "custom" or some other approach.
2. To also get "read your
   writes" consistency, we can have all clients use
   "preference=_primary", because primary shard is first to get all
   writes. This however will probably have worse performance than
   "custom" mode due to no distribution. And that's quite similar to what other people here said about Ignite and Hazelcast.

Right?

Of course that's a solution specifically for ES. Reverting to my initial question which is a bit more generic, turns out that options #2 and #3 are really considered good enough for many distributed systems, with #3 being possible to achieve with #2 (even without immediate support for #3 by DB).